# Find if Regex is Not Matched in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a powershell script which I use to reorder the information in a collection of word documents which contain listings of multiple barcodes (in the format of a string of 6 numbers) and user information into one spreadsheet and any users with unknown barcodes into another. I would like to add in a line to also include any users with no barcodes into the unknown barcode file, as currently these users are being lost in processing.

I have a regex that I use to pick out the barcodes, and I have tried checking the $matches variable for $matches -eq '' or $matches -eq $null, which returns either no output or every user on the sheet, respectively. I have also tried checking the variable I am storing the barcodes in for if it is $null or empty with the same results. Finally I attempted writing another regex to check if there is no match for the format the barcodes come in, which returned every user on the sheet.

Here is a sample of the fields I am working with and their properties:

```
#This is the field which would contain barcodes. Note that there are several instances
#of fields with this name in any given sheet. The text is stored in the Result property,
#and for this field it should include a listing of 6-digit numbers possibly including 
#letters to indicate the type of equipment the barcode represents. It will sometimes
#contain notes from whomever filled the sheet in.
Application     : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass
Creator         : **REDACTED**
Parent          : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass
Type            : 70
Name            : Text10
EntryMacro      : 
ExitMacro       : 
OwnHelp         : False
OwnStatus       : False
HelpText        : 
StatusText      : 
Enabled         : True
Result          : EQUIPMENT WAS ALREADY MOVED
TextInput       : System.__ComObject
CheckBox        : System.__ComObject
DropDown        : System.__ComObject
Next            : System.__ComObject
Previous        : System.__ComObject
CalculateOnExit : False
Range           : System.__ComObject
------------------------------------------------
Application     : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass
Creator         : **REDACTED**
Parent          : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass
Type            : 70
Name            : Text10
EntryMacro      : 
ExitMacro       : 
OwnHelp         : False
OwnStatus       : False
HelpText        : 
StatusText      : 
Enabled         : True
Result          : 
TextInput       : System.__ComObject
CheckBox        : System.__ComObject
DropDown        : System.__ComObject
Next            : System.__ComObject
Previous        : System.__ComObject
CalculateOnExit : False
Range           : System.__ComObject
-----------------------------------------------
Application     : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass
Creator         : **REDACTED**
Parent          : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass
Type            : 70
Name            : Text10
EntryMacro      : 
ExitMacro       : 
OwnHelp         : False
OwnStatus       : False
HelpText        : 
StatusText      : 
Enabled         : True
Result          : L 123456, M 654321, 456789, D 987654
TextInput       : System.__ComObject
CheckBox        : System.__ComObject
DropDown        : System.__ComObject
Next            : System.__ComObject
Previous        : System.__ComObject
CalculateOnExit : False
Range           : System.__ComObject
```

Here is the code I am working with (which is working perfectly apart from leaving off users with no barcodes), including my most recent failed attempt at picking out these users:

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $false
$word.DisplayAlerts = "wdAlertsNone"
$results = "Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4`n"
$exceptions = "Header2,Header3,Header4`n"
$list = get-childitem 'H:\directory'
foreach($file in $list){
    $path = "H:\directory\$($file.name)"
    $doc = $word.Documents.Open($path)
    $fields = $doc.FormFields
    foreach($field in $fields){
        if ($field.name -eq 'Text2'){
            $ucc = $field.Result.Replace(' / ',",")
            $ucc = $ucc.Replace('/',',')
        }
        elseif($field.name -eq 'Text5'){
            $loc = $field.Result
            }
            $loc = $loc.Trim()
        }
        elseif($field.name -eq 'Text10'){
            if($field.result -like '*UNK*'){
                $exceptions+=$loc + "," + $ucc+"`n"
            }
            #this is where I am storing the barcodes
            $bar = @([regex]::matches($field.Result,'\D*(\d{6})')|%{$_.groups[1].value})
            #this is my attempt at picking out blank codes
            if([regex]::Match($field.result,"*(\d[6])*") -ne $true){
                $exceptions+=$loc + "," + $ucc + "`n"
            }
            foreach($code in $bar){
                $results += $code + "," + $loc + "," + $ucc+"`n"
            }
        }
    }
}
$exceptions | out-file 'H:\directory\exceptions.csv' -Encoding ascii -Force
$results | out-file 'H:\directory\list.csv' -Encoding ascii -Force
$word.quit()
[void][System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word)
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired output for a complete [mcve]. Maybe consider formatting (e.g. newlines, paragraphs) to make the question more readable.

Comment: `"*(\d[6])*"` looks like matching "any number of absolutely nothing (probably syntax error), followed by any number of captured groups of digit and 6". Is there anything unusual about the regex flavor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142654/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-cameron).

Answer (score 1):

You could restructure things a bit to do this with a `Where` statement piped to a `ForEach` loop, and utilizing the automatic variable `$Matches`.

```
            $bar = $field.Result | Where{$_ -match '\D*(\d{6})'} | ForEach{$Matches[1].value}
            If(!$bar -eq $null){
                foreach($code in $bar){
                    $results += $code + "," + $loc + "," + $ucc+"`n"
                }
            }Else{
                $exceptions+=$loc + "," + $ucc + "`n"
            }
```

**Edit:** I added in some objects to emulate your sample data, and for each one I generate some random letters for the `$loc` and `$ucc` variables. Then I just output to screen rather than to file. Here's what I'm looking at:

```
$letters= 97..123|%{[char]$_}
$fields = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{'Name' = 'Text10';'Result' = @('asdf123456','dasrew345678','fdswer098765')},
    [pscustomobject]@{'Name' = 'Text10';'Result' = 'EQUIPMENT WAS ALREADY MOVED'},
    [pscustomobject]@{'Name' = 'Text10';'Result' = ''}
)
foreach($field in $fields){
    $loc = (Get-Random -Count 5 -InputObject $letters) -join ''
    $ucc = (Get-Random -Count 5 -InputObject $letters) -join ''
    if ($field.name -eq 'Text2'){
        $ucc = $field.Result.Replace(' / ',",")
        $ucc = $ucc.Replace('/',',')
    }
    elseif($field.name -eq 'Text5'){
        $loc = $field.Result
        #}
        $loc = $loc.Trim()
    }
    elseif($field.name -eq 'Text10'){
        if($field.result -like '*UNK*'){
            $exceptions+=$loc + "," + $ucc+"`n"
        }
        $bar = $field.Result | Where{ $_ -match '\D*(\d{6})' } | ForEach {$Matches[1]}
        If(!($bar -eq $null)){
            foreach($code in $bar){
                "results+=$code + `",`" + $loc + `",`" + $ucc"
            }
        }Else{
            "exceptions+=$loc + `",`" + $ucc"
        }
    }
}
```

That output 5 lines. Three for the first object, all for the same "user" with the same 5 characters for the loc and ucc, and then one barcode per line. Then it output 2 more lines for the records with no barcodes.

```
results+=123456 + "," + vpsjt + "," + lmsyv
results+=345678 + "," + vpsjt + "," + lmsyv
results+=098765 + "," + vpsjt + "," + lmsyv
exceptions+=hbptn + "," + ugydn
exceptions+=ygbop + "," + zy{mt
```

Comment: Thank you for the improved regex, I will use that in my code. However, this style of looping is still returning every user and field as a separate line regardless of whether they have barcodes or not.

Comment: When I use your sample data and replace the pertinent code in your script with that it gives me the desired results.

Comment: The issue with that sample data is that it is a series of strings which represent what is discovered from the powershell console. The actual data includes anywhere from 2-8 fields which may or may not contain barcodes, each with the same name, over 20+ word documents. I do not have a way to accurately transcribe this without uploading the word documents themselves, which is impossible for several reasons.

Comment: So, one document per user, and the document can have multiple fields named 'Text10' that may or may not have barcodes. Does that sum it up?

Comment: Well, there may also be more than one document per user. Apart from that, yes. My workplace takes duplication of labour as a challenge.

Comment: I attempted using your modified regex and if/else statement. This resulted in, for the results, only receiving one barcode per user and the remaining barcodes being dropped. For the exceptions, it returned every field for every user as a separate line.

Comment: It looks like you need to collate results of all documents, then once all documents are processed group the results by user, and then output to files as needed.